# Connect a java class to a separate GUI Jpanel button and/or textarea?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, jbutton

So im linking a java class with array lists and a random array generator to a separate GUI in the same project. Its a Jeopardy Game, so I need the buttons to "get" the strings from the array list and "check" the answer in another. I need to know how to make the GUI "get" info from the other "classes". Thanks.

**(Question&Answer Class Example)**

```
   Random generator = new Random(); 
   int random_int = generator.nextInt(10) + 1;

   double random_int = Math.random() * ( 0 - 24 );     
   String[] am = new String[25];


   String[] ama = new String[25];


   am[0] = "Sam";ama[0] = "Sam";
   am[1] = "Sam";ama[1] = "Sam";
   am[2] = "Sam";ama[2] = "Sam";
  ...
   am[23] = "Sam";ama[23] = "Sam";
   am[24] = "Sam";ama[24] = "Sam";  

  String am_qu = am[random_int];
  String am_an = ama[random_int];
```

**(GUI Jpanel button "Action" Example)**

```
    private void am1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+am_qu+); <--That is what I need to work!

}
```

The Jeopardy game will have buttons that you click which will show dialog box with question, a button that says answer and when that is clicked it will open an input box to check answer after the final submit.

Comment: So... the "am_qu" is not from the same class as the actionPerformed(evt) method? Make it public, or provide getter for it. In general I find your question really vague, so if you want useful input you should clarify it.

Comment: In the GUI Jpanel, it does not allow me to edit the "private".

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: To what class does `am1ActionPerformed` method belong to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how your project is set up, or why your code isn't working, but here's a working snippet I literally just shoved into a `JFrame` of mine:

```
    final Random generator = new Random(); 
    final String[] am = new String[25];
    final String[] ama = new String[25];

    for(int n = 0; n < 25; n++) {
        am[n] = "Sam " + n + " (Q)";
        ama[n] = "Sam " + n + " (A)";
    }

    JButton testButton = new JButton("Click This!");

    testButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {             
            final int random_int = generator.nextInt(24) + 1;
            System.out.println(random_int);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, am[random_int] + " " + ama[random_int]);
        }           
    });
```

See the image below for output:

[image: screenshot of output]

Comment: Hehe, close but not exactly, Ill mark you as right but I already found another way, thanks anyway for the response!